# PyQT + Django system architecture. Is Python a good way?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, pyqt

I need to create 2 level web-system. I choose Python as my tool. 
I want use PyQt to develop 1st level: TCP/IP-server, and Django as 2nd level: Data visualization through Ajax(Front-End). System sketch on **picture**:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pprv9.jpg

1st level will "chat" with about 1000 objects. And web-app with about 200 people.
Is it right way to use Python, Django and PyQt? Or may be there is better architecture solution?

Comment: PyQt is a GUI tool. What does it have to do with creating a TCP/IP server?

Comment: "QtNetwork module contains classes for writing UDP and TCP clients and servers." I think we can run it as service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While PyQt's networking module provides tools for writing TCP servers, I'm not sure you really need that dependency, since TCP servers can be written just in Python using only the standard library, and in fact Python already comes with a [simple HTTP server](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) *built-in* (and so does Django, by the way).

I have nothing against PyQt (quite the contrary, I like it a lot), but mixing its programming model and idioms into a Python program has to be done for a reason, and a network server isn't IMHO a good enough reason. If you want a GUI, then sure. But for a network server, just stick with Python, which has some incredibly powerful libraries of its own for writing servers, the foremost being Twisted, which you should definitely check out.

Comment: Thanks for very useful answer. You'd opened my eyes.

Comment: And is Django a good way to visulize data? I mean is it "Heavy" or not?

Comment: @zenio: Django is a web framework, not a tool to "visualize data". Therefore I'm not sure how to answer this question. I think you should start with the requirements, explaining what you want to achieve exactly - and then you can get recommendations on suitable libraries and framework to use. You can open a new SO question for this purpose - just make sure you explain everything in detail.